# Stop caching of JSON file nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have pulled down an example application running on nodejs.  The application is doing a "get" on a local JSON file for its base configuration and capable to rendering changes on the fly (Netflix Vizceral example app).

I have added a simple setInterval so the client grabs the file every 30 seconds.  The problem is that the client keeps getting the original file from when the server side app was started instead of what is currently there.

**Original:**

```
request.get('sample_data.json')
       .set('Accept', 'application/json')
```

**I have tried variations of:**

```
request.get("sample_data.json?ts="+now,{cache:false})
       .set('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')
```

Not sure I am missing something in the javascript or server side node configuration.

Comment: This is exactly the contents of 'now'.  I see the requests are getting the timestamp as expected but still receiving stale JSON.

Comment: if you browser to that url does it show new data?

Comment: No, it is same data set even though the actual file has been updated.

Comment: Not sure I understand. It this your client code? Your server code? If that's your client code, what's the server code? There are lots of bits of information missing here...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the backend/code you mention (Netflix Vizceral example app), so have you checked wether the server is actually sending the current or a cached version of the file? You cannot bust a cache, if the server is caching the file and always sends the same data.